# Windows Phone Emulator Functions Properly, Debugging or Deploying to Device Does Not

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, emulation

I am developing a very simple application that parses an XML feed, does some formatting and then displays it in a TextBlock. I've added a hyperLink (called "More..) to the bottom of the page (ideally this would be added to the end of the TextBlock after the XML has been parsed) to add more content by changing the URL of the XML feed to the next page.

The issue I'm experiencing is an odd one as the program works perfectly when in the Windows Phone 7 Emulator, but when I deploy it to the device or debug on the device, it works for the first click of the "More..." button, but the ones after the first click just seem to add empty space into the application when deployed or debugged from the device.

I'm using a Samsung Focus (NoDo) and originally thought this may have had to do with the fact that I may not have had the latest developer tools. I've made sure that I am running the latest version of Visual Studio and am still running into the issue.

Here are some snippets of my code to help out.

I've declared the clickCount variable here:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage

     //set clickCount to 2 for second page  
     int clickCount = 2;
```

Here is the snippet of code I use to parse the XML file:

```
    void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            ListBoxItem areaItem = null;

            StringReader stream = new StringReader(e.Result);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
            string areaName = String.Empty;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (reader.Name == "example")
                    {
                        areaName = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();

                        areaItem = new ListBoxItem();
                        areaItem.Content = areaName;
                        textBlock1.Inlines.Add(areaName);
                        textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

and the code for when the hyperLink button is clicked:

```
    private void hyperlinkButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        int stringNum = clickCount;

        //URL is being incremented each time hyperlink is clicked
        string baseURL = "http://startofURL" + stringNum + ".xml";

        Uri url = new Uri(baseURL, UriKind.Absolute);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(url);

        //increment page number
        clickCount = clickCount + 1;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like there's a little more debugging to do here.

Can you test where exactly this is going wrong?

- is it the click that is not working on subsequent attempts?
- is it the HTTP load which is failing?
- is it the adding of inline text which is failing?

Looking at it, I suspect it's the last thing. Can you check that your TextBlock is expecting Multiline text? Also, given what you've written (where you don't really seem to be making use of the Inline's from the code snippet I've seen), it might be easier to append add the new content to a ListBox or a StackPanel rather than to the inside of the TextBlock - ListBox's especially have some benefit in terms of Virtualizing the display of their content.

Comment: I'll do a bit more digging, but here is what I surmise: The click is working as all subsequent clicks add more empty space to the bottom of the textBlock. Not sure about the HTTP load or adding inline Text, that very well may be the cause as well. It's just odd to me that it works perfectly on the emulator, but fails on the device. I used a textBlock mainly because I was having difficulties with wrapping of text in a listBox, it simply didn't work.

Comment: When I click the "More..." button, it gives me more, but doesn't load all of the feed. It cuts off. This makes me wonder if it's a limitation on the size of the textBlock? Both the ScrollViewer and textBlock it encompasses have their Height set to Auto and MaxHeight set to Infinity.

Tested this by setting the height of the textBlock to a very large number, the text cuts off at a certain length, leading me to believe there is another issue. The resizing works as it should, and works well actually.

Comment: Reading this now: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx

It looks like there is a limitation on textBlock size.

Comment: Aaaah - you've have you hit the 2048 limit - I think that limit applies to the height/width of any single control. I'd definitely recommend using a ListBox for what you are doing. That VirtualizingStackPanel inside it will save you memory.